# VLC plays videos with black screen while audio is OK after resuming from suspend

Tags: video, suspend, vlc, totem

> Ubuntu 16.04.3 Xenial
>   VLC 2.2.7
>   Intel® Sandybridge Mobile graphics card

What after resuming from suspend I play a video in VLC it runs with a black screen with good audio output. Meanwhile, totem video player play same video file showing scratching video and good audio.

How to fix this?

Comment: Was the video played before going to suspend mode ? is file located locally ?

Comment: yes video file played very well before suspend. file saved in my hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Tools → Preferences → Video**

Change **Output** to **X11 Video output**